# How to serve data for AJAX calls in a Vue.js-CLI project?

Tags: vue.js

- I have a Vue.js CLI project working.
- It accesses data via AJAX from localhost port 8080 served by Apache.
- After I build the project and copy it to a folder served by Apache, it works fine and can access data via AJAX on that server.
- However, during development, since the Vue.js CLI website is being served by Node.js which is serving on a different port (8081), I get a cross-site scripting error) and want to avoid cross-site scripting in general.

What is a way that I could emulate the data being provided, e.g. some kind of server script within the Vue.js-CLI project that would serve mock data on port 8081 for the AJAX calls during the development process, and thus avoid all cross-site scripting issues?

## Addendum

In my `config/index.js` file, I added a proxyTable:

```
  dev: {
    env: require("./dev.env"),
    port: 8081,
    autoOpenBrowser: true,
    assetsSubDirectory: "static",
    assetsPublicPath: "/",
    proxyTable: {
      "/api": {
        target: "http://localhost/data.php",
        changeOrigin: true
      }
    },
```

And now I make my AJAX call like this:

```
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: '/api',
    data: {
        smartTaskIdCode: 'activityReport',
        yearMonth: '2017-09',
        pathRewrite: {
          "^/api": ""
        }
    }
```

But now I see in my JavaScript console:

> Error: Request failed with status code 404

## Addendum 2

Apparent axios has a problem with rerouting, so I tried it with vue-resource but this code is showing an error:

```
var data = {
    smartTaskIdCode: 'pageActivityByMonth',
    yearMonth: '2017-09'
}
this.$http.post('/api', data).then(response => {
    this.pageStatus = 'displaying';
    this.activity = response.data['activity'];
    console.log(this.activity);
}, response => {
    this.pageStatus = 'displaying';
    console.log('there was an error');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The webpack template has its own documentation, and it has a chapter about API proxying during development:

http://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/proxy.html

If you use that, it means that you will request your data from the node server during development (and the node server will proxy< the request to your real backend), and the real backend directly in production, so you will have to use different hostnames in each environment.

For that, you can define an env variable in `/config/dev.env.js` & `/config.prod.env.js`

Comment: I added a proxyTable in my `config/index.js` file (details above in my post), but now I get the message `Error: Request failed with status code 404`. What do I need to change?

Comment: The pathRewrite in axios seems wrong. Since that happens before the request "leaves your browser", your devserver now receives a POST request to `/`, not `/api`, and so the proxyTable doesn't take effect - consequently, you get a 404

Comment: Yes, I read that axios has a problem with this. I implemented vue-resource (code posted above) but it is not getting the data, also it seems to be accessing the server. Do you see what the problem is?

Comment: Don't think that axios has a general problem, but well. I'm not really familiar with vue-resource, no idea if you use it correctly.

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't work regardless of what I seem to put in the pathRewrite or if it is even present at all.